# Load substring in Hive data input

Tags: hive

I am trying to load an input data file using Hive.

Consider I have the following input in a text file:

"10"

Is it possible to load the input without quotation: as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following third party CSV Serde in the following way.

add jar path/to/csv-serde.jar;

create table table_name (a string, b string, ...)
  row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
  stored as textfile
;

Here is the link: https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde.git